# How can I import several Excel sheets in a multi-index dataframe in Python?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to import an Excel file with several sheets containing the same structure of bidimensional arrays in a multi-indexed Dataframe in Python.

Assume each sheet contains an array (A,B)x(a,b). Basically I would like to have something like this

```
  Sheet1  |   Sheet2   |  Sheet3
   a | b  |   a | b    |  a | b
A 
B
```

I have tried to use a for loop.

```py
df={}
for i in Sheets:
    df[i] = pd.read_excel (r'file.xlsx', sheet_name = [i], header=0, index_col=0)
```

I would expect df to be such that, if I recall

```py
df['Sheet1']
```

I can retrieve one of the arrays, and this actually works fine. The problem comes up if I try to recall

```py
df['Sheet1']['a']
```

to retrieve the first column of the first sheet. However, I get the following error message

```py
KeyError: a
```

and I am stuck here.

Answer (score 3):

#### `sheet_name=None` in [pd.read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html)

Will produce a dicitonary of all sheets.  Pass that to `pd.concat` with `axis=1`

```
pd.concat(pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', None, index_col=0), axis=1)

  Sheet1    Sheet2    Sheet3   
       a  b      a  b      a  b
A      1  2      1  2      1  2
B      3  4      3  4      3  4
```

You can also limit the sheets by passing a list of names

```
pd.concat(pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', ['Sheet1', 'Sheet2', 'Sheet3'], index_col=0), axis=1)
```